# Issue with setTimeout ()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm pretty new to javascript, and I'm trying to create an automated slideshow. This is the first time I'm using `setTimeout()`. When I added the automation the last image is missing. There is a white/blank rectangle where the image should be and the dots indicating which slide the slideshow is on is not lighting up. Below, I have included what I have so far, and I would really appreciate any advice or guidance on how to fix this issue. Thank you!

Carousel.js

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import './Slider.css'
import BtnSlider from './BtnSlider'
import CarouselData from './CarouselData'

const delay = 3000;

export default function Carousel() {

      const [slideIndex, setSlideIndex] = useState(0)
      const timeoutRef = React.useRef(null);
    
      function resetTimeout() {
        if (timeoutRef.current) {
          clearTimeout(timeoutRef.current);
        }
      }
    
      React.useEffect(() => {
        resetTimeout();
        timeoutRef.current = setTimeout(
          () =>
          setSlideIndex((prevIndex) =>
              prevIndex === CarouselData.length - 1 ? 0 : prevIndex + 1
            ),
          delay
        );
      
      return () => {
          resetTimeout();
        };
      }, [slideIndex]);
   
    const nextSlide = () => {
        if(slideIndex !== CarouselData.length){
            setSlideIndex(slideIndex + 1)
        } 
        else if (slideIndex === CarouselData.length){
            setSlideIndex(1)
        }
    }

    const prevSlide = () => {
        if(slideIndex !== 1){
            setSlideIndex(slideIndex - 1)
        }
        else if (slideIndex === 1){
            setSlideIndex(CarouselData.length)
        }
    }

    const moveDot = index => {
        setSlideIndex(index)
    }

    return (
        <div className="container-slider">
            {CarouselData.map((obj, index) => {
                return (
                    <div
                    key={obj.id}
                    className={slideIndex === index + 1 ? "slide active-anim" : "slide"}
                    >
                        <img 
                        src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + `/Imgs/img${index + 1}.jpg`} 
                        alt="images"/>
                    </div>
                )
            })}
            <BtnSlider moveSlide={nextSlide} direction={"next"} />
            <BtnSlider moveSlide={prevSlide} direction={"prev"}/>

            <div className="container-dots">
                {Array.from({length: 3}).map((item, index) => (
                    <div 
                    onClick={() => moveDot(index + 1)}
                    className={slideIndex === index + 1 ? "dot active" : "dot"}
                    ></div>
                ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

CarouselData.js

```
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";

const CarouselData = [
  {
    id: uuidv4(),
    title: "Lorem ipsum",
    subTitle: "Lorem"
  },
  {
    id: uuidv4(),
    title: "Lorem ipsum",
    subTitle: "Lorem"
  },
  {
    id: uuidv4(),
    title: "Lorem ipsum",
    subTitle: "Lorem"
  },

];

export default CarouselData;
```

Comment: i think `setTimeInterval ` is the one you need

Comment: @sojin So instead should I have:                                                     ```timeoutRef.current = setInterval( () =>  setSlideIndex((prevIndex) => prevIndex === CarouselData.length - 1 ? 0 : prevIndex + 1 ), delay );```

Comment: NO no,
just use it in a usEffect and that is enough. no need to cleat timer on every change